# A chessboard problem?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, puzzle, chessboard

Some number of pebbles are placed on a 7x7 chessboard, such that each pebble is placed inside a square and each unit square has at most one pebble. If each row and column of the chessboard contains an even number of pebbles, how many pebbles can be there be all together? (Note:- At first, the problem seemed like a piece of cake but since it appeared in an olympiad so I think it is more complicated than I think. I got the answer as 36 but I think its not true. I don't know the correct answer. Please help.  )

Comment: But there should  be maximum no of pebbles as 16 is also an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the maximum number of pebbles, we should place the maximum number possible – 6 – in each row and column. This makes for a total of **42** pebbles, and can be done by filling in everything but a diagonal.

```
.oooooo
o.ooooo
oo.oooo
ooo.ooo
oooo.oo
ooooo.o
oooooo.
```

Comment: How would one prove that this is the optimal solution? (I know its pretty obvious that it can't get better, but, like, math ya'know?)

Comment: @Airdish Say we have 43 or more pebbles. By pigeonhole one row must have seven pebbles, which can't be.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!